# Agregação de objetos CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, mvc, codeigniter-3

Estou com uma dúvida relacionada à agregação de objetos utilizando o CodeIgniter 3.1.9.

Possuo o seguinte método no *Model*:

```
public function get_tickets($where = array())
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tickets');
    $this->db->where($where);

    return $this->db->get()->result('Ticket');
}
```

O qual faz uma consulta simples no banco de dados e retorna um `array` com os objetos instanciados de uma classe localizada dentro de `/libraries/` chamada `Ticket` que já está carregada na memória. Segui conforme este [exemplo](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#custom-result-objects).

Entretanto, os objetos da classe `Ticket` possuem outro objeto de outra classe agregado, no caso, a classe `Solicitante`.

```
+-----------------------------+               +-------------------+
| Ticket                      |               | Solicitante       |
+-----------------------------+               +-------------------+
| - id          : integer     |               | - id    : integer |
| - solicitante : Solicitante |  0..*         | - nome  : string  |
| - titulo      : string      |<>-------------| - email : string  |
| - descricao   : string      |               | - senha : string  |
| - prazo       : DateTime    |               | - ativo : string  |
| - criado_em   : DateTime    |               +-------------------+
+-----------------------------+
```

A classe `Ticket` já possui o atributo `private $solicitante` e o *getter* e *setter* para este atributo implementados:

```
public function set_solicitante(Solicitante $solicitante)
{
    $this->solicitante = $solicitante;
}

public function get_solicitante()
{
    return $this->solicitante;
}
```

As tabelas no banco de dados estão desta forma:

```
+----+------------------------------+    +----+------------------------------+
|    | tb_tickets                   |    |    | tb_solicitantes              |
+----+------------------------------+    +----+------------------------------+
| PK | id INT (11) AUTO_INCREMENT   |    | PK | id INT (11) AUTO_INCREMENT   |
| FK | id_solicitante INT (11)      |    |    | nome VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL   |
|    | titulo VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL |    |    | email VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL  |
|    | descricao TEXT NOT NULL      |    |    | senha VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL |
|    | prazo DATETIME NOT NULL      |    |    | ativo CHAR (1) DEFAULT 'S'   |
|    | criado_em DATETIME NOT NULL  |    +-----------------------------------+
+----+------------------------------+
```

Pensei em implementar um construtor na classe `Ticket` e chamar um método de outro *Model* que instanciará o objeto `$solicitante`, por exemplo. Porém acho que isso acaba sendo inviável em termos de performance. Pois para cada ticket, uma outra consulta teria que ser feita.

Talvez utilizar `INNER JOIN` no método `get_tickets()` seja a melhor solução, porém não sei se é possível já instanciar o `Ticket` e o `Solicitante` que agregado de uma só vez.

Alguém pode me ajudar? Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Quais são as classes envolvidas? (tipo cade a classe Ticket) e suas relações) e as tabelas envolvidas? tudo isso é relevante para dar uma resposta!

Comment: Entendo.
Adicionei a relação entre as duas classes através do diagrama e as tabelas do banco de dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente, criaria dois modelos que representasse cada tabela, no seu caso em especifico `Tickets` e `Solicitantes` da seguinte forma:

Dentro da pasta `application` cria outra pasta com o nome de `entities` (o nome pode ser de sua preferencia), e um arquivo de base com o nome `Base.php` com o código a seguir:

```
<?php

abstract class Base
{
    public function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->$name;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
}
```

com esse arquivo de `base` as duas classes:

```
<?php

class Solicitante extends Base
{
    protected $id;
    protected $nome;
    protected $email;
    protected $senha;
    protected $ativo;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getNome()
    {
        return $this->nome;
    }
    public function setNome($nome)
    {
        $this->nome = $nome;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getSenha()
    {
        return $this->senha;
    }
    public function setSenha($senha)
    {
        $this->senha = $senha;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getAtivo()
    {
        return $this->ativo;
    }
    public function setAtivo($ativo)
    {
        $this->ativo = $ativo;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

e

```
<?php

class Ticket extends  Base
{
    protected $id;
    protected $id_solicitante;
    protected $titulo;
    protected $descricao;
    protected $prazo;
    protected $criado_em;
    protected $solicitante;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getIdSolicitante()
    {
        return $this->id_solicitante;
    }
    public function setIdSolicitante($id_solicitante)
    {
        $this->id_solicitante = $id_solicitante;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getTitulo()
    {
        return $this->titulo;
    }
    public function setTitulo($titulo)
    {
        $this->titulo = $titulo;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getDescricao()
    {
        return $this->descricao;
    }
    public function setDescricao($descricao)
    {
        $this->descricao = $descricao;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getPrazo()
    {
        return $this->prazo;
    }
    public function setPrazo($prazo)
    {
        $this->prazo = $prazo;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getCriadoEm()
    {
        return $this->criado_em;
    }
    public function setCriadoEm($criado_em)
    {
        $this->criado_em = $criado_em;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getSolicitante()
    {
        return $this->solicitante;
    }
    public function setSolicitante($solicitante)
    {
        $this->solicitante = $solicitante;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

para subir essas classes tem que configurar a *pastas/arquivo* `vendor/autoload.php` (dentro do `config.php` na chave `$config['composer_autoload'] = './vendor/autoload.php';`) para o carregamento, abra o arquivo `composer.json` que está na raiz do seu projeto e configure o `psr-4`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "application/entities/"
    }
}
```

dê o comando `php composer.phar dump` para subir essa configurações e consequentemente as classes que foram criadas e as novas que posteriormente possam criar.

Preparando os `models`: após esse momento crie os dois arquivos responsável em buscar informações em suas tabelas dentro da pasta `application/models`:

```
<?php

class Ticket_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function find($id, $load_relationship = false)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tb_tickets');
        $result = $this->db->get()->row(0, 'Ticket');
        if ($load_relationship)
        {
            $this->getLoadRelationshipSolicitanteOne($result);
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function all($load_relationship = false)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tb_tickets');
        $result = $this->db->get()->result('Ticket');
        if ($load_relationship)
        {
            $this->getLoadRelationshipSolicitanteAll($result);
        }
        return $result;
    }

    protected function getLoadRelationshipSolicitanteAll($result)
    {
        if (!$this->load->is_loaded('Solicitante_model'))
        {
            $this->load->model('Solicitante_model');
        }
        $values = array_map(function ($o) {
            return (int)$o->id;
        }, $result);

        $solicitantes = $this->Solicitante_model->getAllSolicitantes($values);

        return array_map(function ($c) use ($solicitantes) {
            $res = array_values(array_filter($solicitantes, function ($s) use ($c) {
                return $c->id_solicitante == $s->id;
            }));
            if ($res && count($res) == 1){
                $c->solicitantes = $res[0];
            }
            return $c;
        }, $result);

        return $result;
    }

    protected function getLoadRelationshipSolicitanteOne($result)
    {
        if (!$this->load->is_loaded('Solicitante_model'))
        {
            $this->load->model('Solicitante_model');
        }
        $result->solicitante = $this->Solicitante_model->find($result->id_solicitante);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

e

```
<?php

class Solicitante_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function find($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tb_solicitantes');
        $result = $this->db->get()->row(0, 'Solicitante');
        return $result;
    }

    public function getAllSolicitantes(array $values = array())
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tb_solicitantes');
        $this->db->where_in('id', $values);
        $result = $this->db->get()->result();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Nessa parte ficou encarregado que cada `model` carrega a sua informação, mesmo que dentro do `model` `Ticket_model` tenha que ser carregado o `model` `Solicitante_model` e é bom que seja feito assim, porque qualquer mudança o outros `models` vão receber isso claramente.

***Como usar:***

`1 Ticket`

```
$this->load->model('Ticket_model');
$ticket = $this->Ticket_model->find(1, true);
```

***Resultado:***

```
Ticket Object
(
    [id:protected] => 1
    [id_solicitante:protected] => 1
    [titulo:protected] => Title 1
    [descricao:protected] => Desc 1
    [prazo:protected] => 2019-01-01 00:00:00
    [criado_em:protected] => 2019-01-01 00:00:00
    [solicitante:protected] => Solicitante Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 1
            [nome:protected] => Stack
            [email:protected] => stack@stack.com.br
            [senha:protected] => 102030
            [ativo:protected] => 1
        )

)
```

`Todos Ticket`

```
$this->load->model('Ticket_model');
$it = $this->Ticket_model->all(true);
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Ticket Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 1
            [id_solicitante:protected] => 1
            [titulo:protected] => Title 1
            [descricao:protected] => Desc 1
            [prazo:protected] => 2019-01-01 00:00:00
            [criado_em:protected] => 2019-01-01 00:00:00
            [solicitante:protected] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [nome] => Stack
                    [email] => stack@stack.com.br
                    [senha] => 102030
                    [ativo] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Ticket Object
        (
            [id:protected] => 2
            [id_solicitante:protected] => 2
            [titulo:protected] => Title 2
            [descricao:protected] => Desc 2
            [prazo:protected] => 2019-01-02 00:00:00
            [criado_em:protected] => 2019-01-02 00:00:00
            [solicitante:protected] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [nome] => Web
                    [email] => web@web.com.br
                    [senha] => 102030
                    [ativo] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

<sup>**Observação:** ***Dá para simplificar só você não criar as entidades e trabalhar somente com `arrays` como respostas de todos os seus modelos, mas, esse exemplo pode ser feito isso claramente retirando a primeira parte.***</sup>

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, @VirgilioNovic. A grande questão é o problema de performance, já que ao executar o método `$this->Ticket_model->find(1, true)`, para cada objeto `Ticket`, teria que ser feita 2 consultas. Isso me parece um problema de escalabilidade. Mas vou analisar o código com mais calma e ver qual a melhor forma de resolver o problema.

Comment: @p.gi esse exemplo é só fazer também pra carregar uma com duas SQL somente

Comment: @p.gi foi feita a adequadação para trazer em uma lista os objetos agregados, apenas 2 `SQL` e funções do PHP consegue refletir esse modelo. Não tem nesse caso problema de desempenho, já não tinha só faltava implementar para lista. O Caso inverso tem que ser feito baseado nesse exemplo.

Comment: Muito obrigado, @VirgilioNovic! Pelo que entendi todos os `Tickets` e `Solicitantes` são carregados e posteriormente é feita a associação dos mesmos, é isso? Dessa forma são executados apenas 2 SQLs mesmo. Era uma solução assim que estava procurando, pois da maneira que havia abstraído iria ser um problema de escalabilidade. Vou estudar melhor o seu código e tentar realizar a implementação. De qualquer forma ajudou muito!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode inserir a seguinte estrutura dentro do construtor da classe Ticket:

```
public function __construct($paramsSolicitante) {

    if (isset($paramsSolicitante)) {
        $solicitante = $this->load->library('Solicitante', $this->$paramsSolicitante); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Agradeço o comentário @ViniciusGabriel. Infelizmente não consegui ainda, pois quem instancia os objetos da classe `Ticket`é o próprio CodeIgniter nesta linha do _Model_: `$this->db->get()->result('Ticket');`
Tentei implementar o construtor recebendo parâmetros, mas parece que está vindo sempre como `NULL`.

Comment: @p.gi teria me mostrar como fez? Se puder podemos abrir um chat pra conversar melhor também

Comment: Eu só fiz o seguinte teste implementando este construtor: `public function __construct($params) { var_dump($params); }` para ver se algum parâmetro estava sendo passado quando o método `get_tickets()` do _Model_ é executado. Atualizei a pergunta adicionando o relacionamento entre as classes `Ticket` e `Solicitante` e as tabelas no banco de dados. Obrigado pela ajuda @ViniciusGabriel!